# Add tags to photos mysql

Tags: php, mysql, foreign-keys, relational-database

I am implementing tag based search using `PHP` and `MySQL` where each photo has multiple tags. I will use this tags to search photos.
For example, when I search for a query "building", I want all the photos that have the "building" tag.

Here are my tables:

```
photos(photo_id, name, url)
tags(tag_id, tag, photo_id)
```

is this true? or a better idea is appreciated

Comment: I'd suggest 3 tables. Tags, photos and a link table as you want a many-to-many relationship I would assume.

Comment: You are missing chances if same tag added for multiple photos. (you need normalize with three table)

Comment: @Sachink yes, I have realized the normalizing problem. Can you give me the 3 tables case for my example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Normalize up to Third Normal Form:**

```
photos(photo_id, name, url)
tags(tag_id, tag_name, tag_desc)
```

**refe :**

```
photo_tag_refr(photo_id,tag_id, other_attributes)
```

Answer (score 0):

photos(photo_id, name, url)

tags(tag_id, tag)

tags_photos(tag_id,photo_id)

Search photos by tag example:

```
Select * From `photos` p 
LEFT JOIN `tags_photos` tp ON p.photo_id = tp.photo_id 
LEFT JOIN `tags` t ON tp.tag_id = t.tag_id WHERE t.tag = 'building';
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/47a7e/1